# SQl Query to get data from single row as multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me with this.

I have a table structure as follows

```
Department_name | Owner_ID | Approver_ID
-----------------------------------------
Dept 1          | 1234567  | 1234567
```

Now I want the output based on the employee ID as follows

like

```
select department_name,Role  where Owner_ID= '1234567' or Approver_ID = '1234567'

Department_name | Role
------------------------- 
Dept 1          | Owner
Dept 1          | Approver
```

More importantly, I need to get it as two separate rows as shown above and Role is not a column in the table its value wil be either Approver or Owner based on given ID.

I am unable to figure out how to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which table your Column "Role" is available?

Comment: i dont have the role column. I need to get it based on the owner id and Approver id. If Id given = Owner_Id Role is owner and if id= Approver_ID Role is Approver and if both Owner_ID=Approver_ID=given Id ,I need to get them as two seperate rows as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be a union: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f13c9/5/0

```
SELECT
  Department_name,
  'Owner'
FROM test
WHERE Owner_ID = 1234567

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Department_name,
  'Approver'
FROM test
WHERE Approver_ID = 1234567
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i apply order by in this query..?

Comment: @Sravan: in that case you need to use this as a subquery: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdf8f/1/0

Comment: You can apply `ORDER BY` only at the end of the last query, in this case right after the `WHERE Approver_ID = 1234567` line.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This..

```
SELECT Department_name,
CASE WHEN Role = (SELECT Owner_ID FROM Department) 
THEN 'Owner' ELSE 'Approver'
END AS Role
FROM Department
UNPIVOT(Role for Column1 in(Owner_ID,Approver_ID)) AS Role
```

Comment: For this solution your owner_id and approver_id must be different in a row

Comment: both will be in the same row

Comment: you owner_id and approver_id must be different for my solution.
Just change the approver_id and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use APPLY operator

```
SELECT t.Department_name, o.Role       
FROM dbo.YourTable t 
  CROSS APPLY (
               VALUES(CASE WHEN t.Owner_ID = '1234567' THEN 'Owner' END),
                     (CASE WHEN t.Approver_ID = '1234567' THEN 'Approver' END)
               ) o(Role)
WHERE o.Role IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this

SELECT Department_name , Role
    FROM TableName
    UNPIVOT (Role for Department_name in (Owner_ID , Approver_ID)) AS Role

Comment: how can i get the role as owner and approver